# Закрыть приложение после вызова подпроцесса

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, subprocess

Есть приложение на *PyQt5*, которое через **`subprocess`** вызывает другую программу (*xed*, к примеру). 
Нужно закрыть окно приложения на *PyQt*, но чтобы при этом не закрылось открытое приложение.

Открытое приложение не закрывается, если убить окно главного из вне 
(через `xkill`). 
Мне нужен такой же эффект, только изнутри самого приложения.

```
    def exec(self):
        p = subprocess.Popen("echo "+self.lineEdit.text()+" | sudo -S "+self.cmd, shell=True)

        self.lineEdit.setText("")
        t = p.communicate()[0], p.returncode 

        if p.returncode != 0:
            s.kill()
            self.label_4.setText("Пароль введён неверно!")
        else: 
            self.close()
```

Закрывается главное окно, только после того, как закроется запущенное через него приложение, а мне нужно, чтобы оно закрылось сразу же, после открытия другого приложения.

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста минимальный пример демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: @S.Nick, хорошо, сейчас в вопрос добавлю.

Answer (score 0):

Запустил два процесса и закрыл основное приложение.

```
import subprocess
from PyQt5.QtCore    import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout


class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.pushButtonPrint = QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButtonPrint.setText("Click Me!")
        self.pushButtonPrint.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButtonPrint_clicked)

        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(self)
        self.layoutVertical = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.pushButtonPrint)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.textEdit)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButtonPrint_clicked(self):

        cmd = 'python _QPushButton-SignalsExample.py'                       # python
        output = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)  # 

        exePath = "C:/Windows/system32/calc.exe"                            # .exe
        subprocess.Popen(exePath)                                           #

        self.close()                                                        # <<<===                                   


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')
    main = MyWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Забыл указать, что использую линукс. Но, думаю, проблем не должно возникнуть.

Comment: Увы, но нет. Окно главного приложения остаётся открытым, пока не закрою запущеное из него.

Comment: У меня перед self.close() Popen с аргументом shell=True, это влияет? Просто там команда, которую не получается разбить на массив из-за того, что оно воспринимает как программу только первый эл-т массива, а остальные для него аргументы. А так принимает строку.